# Object from array list is left out after removing specific object

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with the method for removing an object from the array of objects using the string input.  I'm only getting the object p2 as the output after removing p1.  P3 is supposed to show up too but I don't know why it's getting skipped.  I don't know what to do from here since I'm a beginner at Java.  Please help.

```
public class Main {
    
    static int plantIndex = 0;
            
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        Plant p1 = new Plant("Hydrangea", "blue");
        Plant p2 = new Plant("Hibiscus", "Pink");
        Plant p3 = new Plant("Rose", "Red");


        Plant[] plants = new Plant[3];
        
        
        addPlant(plants, p1);
        addPlant(plants, p2);
        addPlant(plants, p3);
                        
        display(plants);
        
        search(plants, "Rose");
        
        remove(plants, "Hydrangea");
        
        display(plants);
        
    }
        
            
    public static void addPlant(Plant[] plants, Plant p) {
        
        plants[plantIndex] = p;
        
        System.out.println("You added: \n" + plants[plantIndex]);

        plantIndex++;
        
    }
    

    public static void display(Plant[] plants) {

        System.out.println("Displaying: ");
        
        for(int i=0; i<plantIndex; i++) {
            
            System.out.println(plants[i]); 
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void search(Plant[] plants, String n) {
        
        
        for(int i=0; i<plantIndex; i++) {
            
            if(plants[i].getName().equals(n)) {
                                
                System.out.println("You searched for: \n" + plants[i]);
                                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public static void remove(Plant[] plants, String n) {

        int newIndex=-1;
        
        for(int i=0; i<plantIndex; i++)
        
        {
            
            if(plants[i].getName().equals(n))
                
            {
                System.out.println("You removed: \n" + plants[i]);

                continue;
            }
            
            plants[++newIndex] = plants[i];
            
        }
        
        plantIndex = newIndex;
    }
}
```

```
class Plant {

    String name; 
    String color;

    public Plant(String name, String color) {
        
        this.setName(name);
        this.setColor(color);
        
    }


    public String toString() {
        
        return "Name: " + name + ", Color: " + color + "\n";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting wrong `newIndex` value. When you remove 1 element from 3 element array `newIndex` value become 1, but looking on your app logic it should be 2. To fix it change initial `newIndex` value in `remove()` method and change `prefix` increment to `postfix` increment

```
public static void remove(Plant[] plants, String n) {

    int newIndex = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < plantIndex; i++) {

        if(plants[i].getName().equals(n)) {
            System.out.println("You removed: \n" + plants[i]);

            continue;
        }

        plants[newIndex++] = plants[i];

    }

    plants[newIndex] = null;

    plantIndex = newIndex;
}
```

Also you didn't actually remove elements from array. To do it add this line

```
plants[newIndex] = null;
```

Output after 1 delete

```
You removed: 
Name: Hydrangea, Color: blue

Displaying: 
Name: Hibiscus, Color: Pink

Name: Rose, Color: Red
```

Output after 2 delete

```
You removed: 
Name: Rose, Color: Red

Displaying: 
Name: Hibiscus, Color: Pink
```

Output after 3 delete

```
You removed: 
Name: Hibiscus, Color: Pink

Displaying:
```